# pyplot is bleeding into background using 3d array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to generate maps of wind data using a 3d array described as:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (gust_cat: 3, rose_group: 80, latitude: 1377, longitude: 2145)
Coordinates:
  * gust_cat     (gust_cat) int64 1 2 3
  * rose_group   (rose_group) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
Dimensions without coordinates: latitude, longitude
Data variables:
    lat          (latitude, longitude) float64 ...
    lon          (latitude, longitude) float64 ...
    ws10m_mean   (latitude, longitude) float64 ...
    gust_number  (latitude, longitude, gust_cat) float64 ...
    rose_number  (latitude, longitude, rose_group) int64 ...
Attributes:
    version:          Created in 2023
    Grid_resolution:  2.5 X 2.5 km
```

The data I'm interested in is the gust_number. I want to generate map of the data but am having troubles. When they are generated it seems that the background is filled with a value that doesn't exist since anything outside CONUS is not modeled. Here are the images for `gust_number1` and `gust_number2`, respectively.
[image]

[image]

The last map is made with the `gust_number3` variable and is correct. No bleeding or anything strange happening.

[image]

I'm wondering if the way I'm passing the 3D array to contourf is causing this background bleeding to happen but I'm not sure. The top two correspond to first and second index so maybe it has to do with the last map using the last dimension in the array. Any help would be appreciated.

Full code to generate maps is below.

mapGen.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cartopy.crs as ccrs,matplotlib,argparse
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from matplotlib import ticker, cm

def StaticMap(dataset,variable,filename,output):
    titles = {
        "ws10m_mean":[dataset['ws10m_mean'].values,'Average Wind Speed (mph)'],
        "gust_number1":[(dataset['gust_number'].values)[:,:,0],'Gust Hours 18-30 mph'],
        'gust_number2':[(dataset['gust_number'].values)[:,:,1],'Gust Hours 30-45 mph'],
        'gust_number3':[(dataset['gust_number'].values)[:,:,2],'Gust Hours 45+ mph']
    }

    fig = plt.figure()
    mercator = ccrs.Mercator(central_longitude=-99.6,min_latitude=20,max_latitude=50)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mercator)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,linestyle=':')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('10m'))
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES,alpha=0.5)

    preplot = ax.contourf(dataset.lon.values,dataset.lat.values,titles[variable][0],transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap='viridis_r',levels=100)
       
    plt.colorbar(preplot,orientation='horizontal')

    plt.title(f"{titles[variable][1]}")
    fig.text(.5,.05,f"{filename}",ha='center')
    
    plt.savefig(output,dpi=500)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Monthly API Statistics')
    parser.add_argument('-i',action='store',metavar=('filename'),help='file to read',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-s',action='store',metavar=('variable'),help='variable to map',required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-o',action='store',metavar=('filename'),help='file to output',required=True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    xnc = xr.open_dataset(args.i)
    StaticMap(xnc,args.s,args.i,args.o)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```